# What techniques were used to film zero-g scenes in The Expanse?

Tags: film-techniques, the-expanse

Most of the zero-g scenes in the SyFy series *The Expanse* appear to be done with good old cables, some CGI, and actors moving slowly.

But there is one scene at the very beginning of the first episode, where Julie Mao is trapped and weightless in a small room, and, notably, her hair appears weightless. An extended version of the scene is also seen in a flashback in episode 9.

How was that scene filmed? Water tank and color grading? Vomit comet flight? CG hair?

Comment: How they depict and the amount of thought given to gravity really stands out for this series. +1 for delving into that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How was that scene filmed?

### Wirework and CGI for the hair.

[**Syfy**](http://www.syfy.com/theexpanse/videos/all/5486) has an "Inside The Expanse" series of 'behind the scenes' videos.

In the case of this specific scene, it's shown at the very beginning of the first instalment.

[image]

These are also on Youtube.

Episode 1:

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for some behind-the-scenes stuff before I asked, but never found this. I also looked at the scene again, and that hair is pretty well done. Its movement seems ever so slightly not-quite-right, but the lighting effects are spot on, and made me think it was still real hair, just under water maybe.